# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\expense-tracker_fullstack-master\frontend\С:'

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-modules, mern

Running server in project - all good, when trying run frontend, have a problem.

```
PS E:\expense-tracker_fullstack-master\frontend> npm start

> frontend@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start

node:internal/fs/utils:350
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\expense-tracker_fullstack-master\frontend\С:'
    at Object.realpathSync (node:fs:2655:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\expense-tracker_fullstack-master\frontend\node_modules\temp-dir\index.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\expense-tracker_fullstack-master\frontend\node_modules\tempy\index.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'E:\\expense-tracker_fullstack-master\\frontend\\С:'
}
```

Debug log:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.8.1
2 info using node@v18.18.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 3ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\alexm\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.18.0\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 4ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 5ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:E:\expense-tracker_fullstack-master\frontend\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\alexm\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 15ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 15ms
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm start
22 verbose argv "start"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 2ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 0ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\alexm\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-07T11_30_24_913Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\alexm\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-07T11_30_24_913Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 43ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 97ms
31 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 3 files
32 silly logfile error removing log file C:\Users\alexm\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-07T11_03_16_946Z-debug-0.log [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\alexm\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-07T11_03_16_946Z-debug-0.log'] {
32 silly logfile   errno: -4048,
32 silly logfile   code: 'EPERM',
32 silly logfile   syscall: 'lstat',
32 silly logfile   path: 'C:\\Users\\alexm\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_logs\\2023-10-07T11_03_16_946Z-debug-0.log'
32 silly logfile }
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 timing command:run-script Completed in 1538ms
35 timing command:start Completed in 1548ms
36 verbose exit 1
37 timing npm Completed in 1821ms
38 verbose code 1
```

Running server in project - all good, when trying run frontend, have a problem.
Try on another PC, his running... Install another version version Visual Code, Node, doing install,audit,fix, delete node_modules and another. I don't what his need in my C drive.. Thinking, reinstall Windows can help, but i want try to fix in this system.

Comment: Please tag your post with the framework you are using, so experts can see and help you out. Are you using [tag:react]? VS Code is not relevant here if you are simply running `npm start` from the command line. Or are you using any VS Code extensions to run your app, like code-runner?

Comment: Not an expert on frontend, but looks like you have a misconfiguration in one of your app files: "*E:\expense-tracker_fullstack-master\frontend\С:*"